# It is possible to hide the Discovery menu?

Tags: xslt, dspace

Since version 4 the discovery is standard on dspace structure unlike previous versions they had to be activated. It is possible to disable it or hide it? with any configuration without having to modify code or xslt files.

Comment: You will need to modify some files for this (as far as I am aware)

Comment: Managed by the settings in discovery.xml file, i deactivated facets of discovery, however there is still the part of login and specific search, that are displaying. Suggestions?

Comment: I found a very easy but not so advisable solution is to hide with CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to completely disable Discovery, then I think you can do it by following those two steps.

Fist in config/dspace.cfg, you should change the event system configuration: replace

```
event.dispatcher.default.consumers = versioning, discovery, eperson, harvester
```

by

```
event.dispatcher.default.consumers = versioning, search, browse, eperson, harvester
```

Then, in config/xmlui.xconf, you should enable the old Lucene search aspect (look for the Search Engines section in the document).

A full Lucene re-index will be necessary.

Not tested personally, this should work on DSpace 4 and 5 XMLUI, however.

Cheers,
Benoît